# Python twisted with mysql : sending the request to the server one by one, but response is getting delayed

Tags: python, mysql, twisted, cleardb

We have been using  Twisted Python TCP socket server with the mysql db for more that 6 months now.We are facing the issue that our chat module is lagging when 4-5 clients are connecting to the server and tried to use the app for chatting. and sometimes our chat server stops responding completely.  I mean no requests are sent and nobody can see the posts which they have posted. After sometime it's like all the responses just send at once and the client got 6-7 or more posts at a time.We have a logic also behind the every posts.

How to handle this lag?..

Comment: are you using non-blocking mysql library?

Comment: I agree with Dmitry the behaviour you're describing looks like you've got one function call that is perhaps blocking your reactor. When that function is done all others will get executed suddenly in bulk (if there's nothing else blocking the reactor).